# Añadir efectos de una clase CSS a otra

Tags: css

Quiero obtener los estilos que tiene la clase `.class-one` y que se añadan a la clase `.class-inheritance`. ¿Hay manera de hacerlo?

```
.class-one {
  color: black;
}

.class-inheritance {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: lo que deberias hacer es ponerle las dos clases a la etiqueta html para que tenga las dos propiedades de estilos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en la clase en html puedes poner mas de una clase, y aprovechando eso le pones las clases que quieres sin necesidad de heredar nada, y puedes tener el estilo de una clase base y añadirle mas

```css
.font-green{
    color:green;
}

.red{
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<span class="red font-green">HOLA</span>
<span class="font-green">HOLA</span>
<span class="red">HOLA</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar el hecho de que las dos clases empiezan por `class`. Puedes crear unas reglas que se aplican a todas las clases que empiezan por `class`:

```
[class ^="class"] {...}
```

```css
[class ^="class"] {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  color: black;
}

.class-one {
  
}

.class-inheritance {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="class-one">class-one</div>
<div class="class-inheritance">class-inheritance</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es juntar ambas clases en un mismo conjunto de reglas de estilo, es decir así: `.class1, .class2`

A continuación te dejo un ejemplo.

```css
.cls1, .cls2{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cls1">
  <p>Parrafo 1 con la primer clase</p>
 </div>
 <br><br>
 <div class="cls2">
  <p>Parrafo 2 con la segunda clase<p>
  </div>
```